# How to generate a time series vector(2001/01, 2001/02,.....)?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, lubridate

I have a 240 rows data(temperature from 2001.01 to 2020.12).

I want to generate a vector just like

```
c(2001/01, 2001/02,...2001/12,2002/01,......2020/12)
```

to plot a time series figure.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(tem= runif(240,1,10),
             time=1:240)
ggplot(df,aes(time,tem))+
  geom_line()+
  geom_point()+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

How can I do it in R?

Comment: `seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), by = "1 month")`

Comment: Followed by `format(x, "%Y/%m")` if you want a character vector in the format your provided rather than a `"Date"` object.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will learn and try it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ym` from `lubridate`. Note that the output in your desired format is a string. `date`s are internally always stored in a standardized format (numerical), e.g. "2023-01-01 12:12:12", corresponding to `%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S`

```
library(lubridate)

begin <- "2001/01"

end <- "2001/04"

format(seq.Date(ym(begin), ym(end), "month"), "%Y/%m")
[1] "2001/01" "2001/02" "2001/03" "2001/04"
```

If you want a time series object of class `ts`

```
begin <- c(2001, 1)

end <- c(2001, 4)

ts(1:4, start = begin, end = end, frequency = 12)
     Jan Feb Mar Apr
2001   1   2   3   4
```

EDIT:
The edit changes the answer significantly (almost worthy a different answer), still add it here. Basically just add a date object and do the format in `ggplot2` with `scale_x_date`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(42)

begin <- "2001/01"

end <- "2001/10"

df <- tibble(tem = runif(10, 1, 10), 
             time = seq.Date(ym(begin), ym(end), "month"))

ggplot(df, aes(time, tem)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme_bw() + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%Y/%m", date_breaks = "1 month")
```

[image: line plot]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have edited my description. My main aim is plot a figure.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just `plot` it maybe.

```
plot(df$tmp, type='o', pch=20, xaxt='n', xlab='date', ylab='temperature', main='My Header')
axis(1, axTicks(1)[-1], df$date[axTicks(1)])
```

[image]

---

*Data:*

```
v <- seq(as.Date("2001-01-01"), as.Date("2020-12-01"), "month")
set.seed(42)
df <- data.frame(date=strftime(v, "%Y.%m"), tmp=rnorm(length(v)))
```